# How can you Extend a UI Extension in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have a client that has Manufacturing installed.  On the Stock Item Screen the MFG code adds a Manufacturing tab. I want to add a new field to the Manufacturing tab, but I do not want to update the MFG customization package as it will cause issues when a new MFG build comes out.  How can I extend the screen extensions of another customization package?

Others have suggested copying the MFG code to another Customization Project and modifying that, but that would mean that I am constantly having to maintain third party code every time they have a new build.  This is the situation that I am trying to avoid as we already have an instance where we have a setup of base code and three different copies for three different clients.

Please note I am using MFG as the example as I have run into this issue a few times with various third party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this from Acuamtica support:

As you may know we are migrating to the new UI technology and we are going to get rid of Web forms and aspx completely. After that the page layout will most likely be represented by C# class with a customization mechanism similar to what we have for graphs or DACs.
It’ll allow you to have multi-level extensions the same way.

The new UI is scheduled to be implemented in 2021R1 or 2021R2.  T

This is not immediate help but at least we know it is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a new customization project, and they use Levels so that your new customization is the last item?

Let's say that you have customization ABC installed (example MFG). You create a new customization XYZ and set this as a level higher than ABC. Make sure that ABC is published, do your customizations on XYZ and then publish all again.

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, you might need to add a dll reference to the ABC project in your XYZ project. This will allow you to use graphs/DACs from the ABC project in your XYZ project.

Comment: If the customization ABC has made a change to a base Acumatica page, added a new tab for example, the new tab will not appear in the new customization in order to be modified.  Right now we are being forces to copy ABC into a new customization package, and make the modifications.  But anytime ABC is updated by the third party ISV, we have to copy to a new customization package and redo our work.  This is not sustainable in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay in getting back. Yes, I understand it can be a bit tedious. But I am not sure why you would need to copy manually. If ABC is updated by your third party, then shouldn't it be just possible to install the new customization project? You might need to redo some changes on your end but I don't think you need to start from scratch. When Acumatica publishes, it actually joins all customization projects into a single one (in the background of course) - so it should handle it for you

Comment: Redoing some of the changes for 1 client ever now and then would be one thing, but if I have 10 clients and we have to redo code for all of them that becomes a nightmare every time the system gets updated.  As we grow it becomes a full time position to maintain the code.  But if Acumatica had a way to extend the extension we would not have to be in this position.